# Disable Razor Viewcompilation

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My current project uses razor pages (.cshtml). Due to JS being thus far large I decided to separate the javascript into js files into the views folder.

example:
Views\Home\Login.cshtml
Views\Home\Login.js

I cannot move them to wwwroot due to them using a ton of localization resources as well as session values.

Now the issue is that for some unknown reason my project automatically compiles these views into a compiledviews.dll. This is unwanted behavior.
Im unable to disable this using the false tag in my .csprj.

How can i compile my project, publish it without my pages being compiled?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be fine using a script bundle and adding it to your`_Layout.cshtml` shared view like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Restaurantes</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/YOUR_BUNDLE")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</head>
```

You can read more about bundles here: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/scriptbundle-mvc